# PHP pagination customize page number

Tags: php, pagination

How to customize the pagination page number below?

Current:

[image]

and what I want is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 Next Last Page
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$Num_Pages; $i++)
{
    if($i != $Page)
    {
        echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i'>$i</a> ]";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<b> $i </b>";
    }
}
```

Any clue how to do this?

Comment: did you need to do it from current page too? E.g. if you are on page 10, then it should show `10 11 12 13 14 Next Last Page`?

Comment: @A.Lau yes, I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try this:

```
$Num_Pages = 70;

//$Page = $_GET['Page'];
$Page = 12;
$from = $Page - ($Page % 5) + 1;

for($i=$from; $i<$from+5 && $i<$Num_Pages; $i++)
{
    if($i != $Page)
    {
        echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i'>$i</a> ]";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<b> $i </b>";
    }
}
$next_page = $Page+1;
echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$next_page '>next</a> ]";
echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Num_Pages'>Last Page</a> ]";
```

Replace the `$Page = 12` with the `$_GET` to get the page dynamically.

Haven't really tested it.

Comment: Hi A. Lau, I tried your code, but why 0 is appear? 0 1 2 3 4, should be 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: forgot the +1, change to this `$from = $Page - ($Page % 5) + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$start_page = intval($Page / 5) *5 + 1;  
$to_page = $start_page + 4;
$is_last_group = ($start_page + 5)> $Num_Pages);
if (is_last_group) 
   $to_page = $Num_Pages;  
for($i = $start_page; $i <= to_page; $i++)
    {
        if($i != $Page)
        {
            echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i'>$i</a> ]";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<b> $i </b>";
        }
    }
if($page < $Num_Pages){
       $next_page = $page + 1;
       echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$next_page '>next</a> ]";
       echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Num_Pages'>last</a> ]";
}
```

Comment: This will still print them all before the next and last, OP wants just four, easy adjustment.